# How to check if a text contains a set of char using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I would like to understand if my message includes a fixed set of chars like

```
<number>:<number>
```

What I am trying is:

```
if (!loggingEvent.RenderedMessage.Contains("[0-9]:[0-9]"))
{
   ...
}
```

but it is not working as I want. How can I fix it? It is in C#.

EDIT

The whole string is like:

```
The server IP is -> 127.1.2.35:9001!
```

Comment: It should be something like `if (!Regex.IsMatch(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage, "^[0-9]+:[0-9]+$"))`. `String.Contains` does not support regex. Also, `[0-9]` matches 1 digit while you probably want to allow 1 or more (that is what `+` ensures). The `^` and `$` anchor the pattern to the string start/end. Certainly you can split the string with `:` and check if both the split values are all numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex approach will look like

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage, "[0-9]+:[0-9]+"))
```

Note that  `String.Contains` does not support regex. Also, `[0-9]` matches 1 digit while you probably want to allow 1 or more (that is what `+` ensures).

See [the online C# demo](http://ideone.com/FHAZ6j) also extracting that substring:

```
var s = "The server IP is -> 127.1.2.35:9001!"; 
var result = Regex.Match(s, @"[0-9]+:[0-9]+");
if (result.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("No match!");
```

Comment: Ty for ur answer. I edited the question, could u please check

Comment: Good, I trimmed my answer to fit the updated requirements.

Comment: you can make it a little less verbose by replacing [0-9] with \d

Comment: @user277498: Unless the Arabic/Hindi/etc. digits are not supposed to ever appear in the string. Yes, in this context, it might be OK to use just `\d`. Or the `\d` can be used with the ECMAScript flag - `Regex.Match(s, @"\d+:\d+", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]:[0-9]");
    Match match = regex.Match("<number>:<number>");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
```

Comment: Ty for ur answer. I edited the question, could u please check